# Some questions about an exercise about $C^\infty \subset L^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let 
$$ L^\infty (\mathbb R) = \{f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C\mid \text{essential sup of } f < \infty \text{ and } f \text{ Borel measurable} \}$$

and

$$ C^\infty (\mathbb R ) = \{ f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C \mid f \text{ continuous }, \lim_{|x|\to \infty}f(x) = 0 \}$$

I was going to solve the following exercise but then realised there were a few things that were not clear to me. Here is the exercise:

Prove that there exists an element $\lambda \in (L^\infty (\mathbb R))^\ast$ such that $\lambda (f) = f(0) $ for all $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$.

Hint: Use consequences of the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Here are my thoughts and questions:

(1) It's clear to me that $C^\infty$ is a subspace of the space of bounded functions $B(\mathbb R)$ but here in this exercise $L^\infty$ is a space consisting of elements that are equivalence classes.

> Is this not a problem? Does $C^\infty$ embed into $L^\infty$? (I'm not
>   sure embed is the correct word...)

(2) Say we use representatives of $L^\infty$ so that (1) is not a problem. Then to me it seems that the evaluation map $f \mapsto f(0)$ is an element of $(L^\infty)^\ast$. And this would answer the question but the hint suggests I am missing something.

> What am I missing?

Comment: for 1) in each equivalence class there is at most one continuous representative. for 2) you also need to show that $f\mapsto f(0)$ is continuous.

Comment: As a note, the standard terminology for what you call $C^\infty$ is $C_0$. $C^\infty(X)$ usually means "infinitely differentiable functions $X \to \mathbb R$".

Comment: @user251257 Yes, but I believe to have written a correct proof that its norm is bounded. But perhaps there is an error I cannot find in my proof. I am really struggling to understand why one has to use Hahn-Banach here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathscr C^{\infty}$ be the vector space of almost-everywhere equivalence classes of elements of $C^{\infty}$. That is, $$\mathscr C^{\infty}\equiv\{[f]\,|\,f\in C^{\infty}\},$$ where, for each $f\in C^{\infty}$, $$[f]\equiv\left\{g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C\,\big|\,g\text{ is Borel measurable and }g\overset{\text{a.e.}}{=}f\right\}.$$ Since almost-everywhere equivalence does not change the essential supremum norm, one has, for any $f\in C^{\infty}$, that $\|[f]\|_{\infty}=\|f\|_{\mathsf u}$, where $\|f\|_{\mathsf u}$ is the usual uniform norm (as you already observed, every $f\in C^{\infty}$ is bounded, so this makes sense). This is because the essential supremum norm of a bounded continuous function is actually equal to the uniform norm. In short, we just proved that $\mathscr C^{\infty}\subseteq L^{\infty}$, where $L^{\infty}$ is the space of equivalence classes of Borel-measurable functions with finite essential suprema.

Define the map $\mu: {\mathscr C}^{\infty}\to\mathbb R$ as $\mu([f])\equiv f(0)$ for each $f\in C^{\infty}$. This is well-defined, since any equivalence class in ${\mathscr C}^{\infty}$ contains exactly one continuous function (it contains at least one by definition, and it cannot contain two, because two continuous functions that are equal almost everywhere are, in fact, equal everywhere). Also, one has that $$|\mu([f])|=|f(0)|\leq\|f\|_{\mathsf u}=\|[f]\|_{\infty},$$ so that $\mu$ is a bounded linear functional on the subspace $\mathscr C^{\infty}$ of $L^{\infty}$. Now you can use the Hahn–Banach theorem to obtain a bounded linear functional $\lambda:L^{\infty}\to\mathbb R$ such that $\lambda([f])=f(0)$ for any $f\in C^{\infty}$; or, less rigorously speaking, “$\lambda(f)=f(0)$ for any $f\in C^{\infty}$.”

This less rigorous statement is formally incorrect (which is probably what caused your confusion), but, at the end of the day, it makes intuitive sense: After all, $\lambda$ is such a functional that picks the (unique) element that is in $ C^{\infty}$ from every equivalence class that contains such an element, and assigns the value of that function at $0$ to the equivalence class.

Comment: Thank you. What I don't understand is why you have to define this evaluation functional only for $C^\infty$ first. Why can we not define it on $L^\infty$? I really want to understand why using Hahn-Banach is necessary here.

Comment: @astudent Because if $[f]$ is a generic equivalence class in $L^{\infty}$, then $f(0)$ may not be well-defined: many functions in the same equivalence class return different values at $0$. Moreover, the resulting functional is not guaranteed to be bounded. For a generic $[f]\in L^{\infty}$, there is no clear relationship between $|f(0)|$ and $\|[f]\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: But if an equivalence class in $L^{\infty}$ contains a continuous function $f\in C^{\infty}$, then you can assign the value $f(0)$ to the class in a well-defined way, because that continuous function will be unique in that class. Moreover, the resulting functional will be bounded: $|f(0)|\leq\|f\|_{\mathsf u}$, and the uniform norm of $f$ will be the same as the ess. sup. norm of $[f]$ as an element of $L^{\infty}$. We use the nice properties of continuous functions to define a well-defined functional on $\mathscr C^{\infty}$ (which would not be possible on $L^{\infty}$) and then we extend it.

Comment: Nice, thank you, that's what I didn't understand. I think I'm starting to understand: If we replace $L^\infty$ with $B$ (just bounded functions, no equivalence classes) then this evaluation map would be in $B^\ast$, right?

Comment: @astudent That's right, the evaluation map $E_x: B\to\mathbb R$, defined as $E_x(f)\equiv f(x)$ for $f\in B$, is in $B^{\star}$ for any $x$ in the underlying space. Indeed, $E_x$ is obviously linear and $$|E_x(f)|=|f(x)|\leq\|f\|_{\mathsf u}\quad\forall f\in B,$$ so that $E_x$ is a bounded functional (and its operator norm is at most $1$).